# MFC CComboBox::InitStorage documentation clarification

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a combo box which I need to populate with potentially a large number of items, I have looked at the MSDN MFC documentation for `CComboBox` and I have found the [`InitStorage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/9eyf7ht2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) member function, with the following prototype:

```
int CComboBox::InitStorage( int nItems, UINT nBytes );
```

The parameters are listed as:

> *nItems*: Specifies the number of items to add.
>
> *nBytes*: Specifies the amount of memory, in bytes, to allocate for item strings.

This sounds like you specify the **total** amount of memory in the `nBytes` parameter. However, the example they give conflicts with this:

```
// The pointer to my combo box.
extern CComboBox* pmyComboBox;

// Initialize the storage of the combo box to be 256 strings with
// about 10 characters per string, performance improvement.
int n = pmyComboBox->InitStorage(256, 10);
ASSERT(n != CB_ERRSPACE);

// Add 256 items to the combo box.
CString str;
for (int i=0;i < 256;i++)
{
   str.Format(_T("item string %d"), i);
   pmyComboBox->AddString( str );
}
```

This example suggests that the `nBytes` parameter is actually the number of bytes to reserve **per string**, rather than in total. And this would make sense considering there is an `nItems` parameter, so the total amount of memory could be easily calculated.

If anyone could clarify this I would be grateful.

Comment: It's unclear whether the `nBytes` parameter refers to bytes per item  (i.e. it results in allocating `nItems * nBytes`) or total allocation. Ultimately, I don't think this matters one way or another: the combo box will always do the right thing internally and this is just an optimization. But if you are so inclined, click "No" under the "Is this Helpful?" link on the MSDN page, and file a report with Microsoft. They *may* update it at some point.

Comment: Whenever I find the MFC documentation unclear I try to look up the respective Windows API instead. In this case ([`LB_INITSTORAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761319.aspx)) seems to indicate that starting with Windows NT 4.0 this combobox message doesn't do anything anymore.

Comment: @Tim The MSDN [`CB_INITSTORAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775872(v=vs.85).aspx) page seems to suggest that whilst it doesn't perform a function for Windows NT 4.0, it does actually do what's expected for Windows 2000/XP (and presumably later versions too). Thank for for the tip about looking up that respective Windows API though, I think that will be very handy in future!

Comment: D'oh... I guess it would have helped had I looked up the right one: `CB_INITSTORAGE`, not `LB_INITSTORAGE`. Thanks for pointing that out, Shaktal. On a related note about looking up API documentation: Occasionally you get updated documents by removing the version postfix from the URL, *(v=vs.85)* in this case. This will take you to the most recent document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information by Raymond Chen would indicate that it is the TOTAL amount required for the strings not PER String.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/10/152612.aspx

This would make sense since it would give more control in situations where the string length is very variable.

Comment: The linked blog moved to: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040610-00/?p=38933